# Write event onclick not via using ng-click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to set event `onclick` for an object not via using `ng-click` like jQuery syntax:

```
<button>Click me</button>
<script>
    $('button').click(function () {
        alert('Hello World!')
    });
</script>
```

My question, is there a way to write event `onclick` like that in angularjs?

I don't want to use this way:

```
<button ng-click="sayhello()">Click me</button>

angular.module('myModule', []).controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sayhello = function () {
        alert('Hello World!');
    };
});
```

I want to hide the information `ng-click="sayhello()"` in the html.

Comment: In my opinion, this would defeat the purpose of using angular in the first place. Directives, such as ng-click are necessary for angular to make sense. Of course, if you are not against using directives, but just want to avoid ng-click for some reason (even though I must admit I can't understand why this would be the case), you can always write your own directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `angular.element`:

```
var ele = angular.element('button');
```

Same Jquery Code:

```
ele.click(function () {
   alert('Hello World!')
});
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/htgqNcWoyE0zbB444ajL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button click-me>Click me</button>

angular.module('myModule')
  .directive('clickMe', function(){
    return {
      link: function(scope, element){
        element.on('click', function(){
          alert('Wassup');
        })
      }
    }
})
```